# How to disable TypeNameHandling for every collections at serialization?

Tags: c#, dynamic, json.net

I'm trying to send some weakly typed data from ASP.NET MVC host to JavaScript client. Weak typing means here either having `object` type property, or having an `ExpandoObject` as a result.

Due to the `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto` setting (which I need for weakly typed objects), I get the `$type` annotations for collections as well, resulting a different JSON structure: instead of having a simple array, I have it wrapped within a `{ $type: ..., $values: ... }` structure.

How could I omit this globally for every kind of collections?

I tried to implement a custom contract resolver, but doesn't seem to work with `ExpandoObject`s.

```
public class JsonWebAPIContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public bool SkipTypNameHandlingOnCollections { get; set; }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (SkipTypNameHandlingOnCollections && property.PropertyType.IsCollectionType())
            property.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None;
        return property;
    }
}
```

In the code I have my good old extension method `Type.IsCollectionType` which works properly. Maybe the problem is that dynamic objects are not "going through" the contract resolving mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that Json.NET created a `DictionaryContract` for my `ExpandoObject`, and this is why it didn't go through the `CreateProperty`. Of course this makes sense at second glance.

So I managed to achieve my goal with the following extension of the above mentioned custom contract resolver.

```
protected override JsonDictionaryContract CreateDictionaryContract(Type objectType)
{
    var c = base.CreateDictionaryContract(objectType);
    if (typeof(IDynamicMetaObjectProvider).IsAssignableFrom( c.UnderlyingType))
        c.ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None;
    return c;
}
```

With this solution I achieved a bit different goal: I turned typename handling off for **every** dynamic property of any dynamic object type, but that's completely OK for me in this scenario.